# How to mirror files on all desktops when running in extended desktop mode

Tags: desktop, preferences, ui

I want to mirror files/shortcuts on all desktops/screens when running in extended desktop mode. I don't want to manually copy them and I also don't want to mirror my displays. 
Is there any way to do this in macOS preferably without external programs.

Comment: The files/folders on Desktop are only shown on the Primary display when using extended display mode. You'll need to open Finder to access files on Desktop on the extended display.

Comment: On an extended desktop, you can’t do that because you would then have 2 copies of the same file/folder.  Remember, your Desktop is a graphical representation of `~/Desktop`.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish, maybe there’s a better way?

Comment: I really just wan't to mirror "the graphical representation of ~/Desktop" to all my "Desktops". That would be the ideal case. Just mirroring the view. I have 3 monitors + my mbp and i primarily use my mbp without external screens. So I wan't to layout my desktop based on the mbps screen. When I then connect it to my docking station I only get the folders/icons etc on one of the screens.